# Insert *whatever* every nth row in Views

Tags: 7, views

I am looking for a solution to insert "something" every nth row in a view.  Technically, that "something" will be an Ad, but in Drupal terms it could be a block, a node, an entity, custom html row...really anything that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Simply add a `tpl` for the view and do **whatever**..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In under `Theme: Information` you'll find `Style output: views-view-table.tpl.php ...`. Override that. I selected the Theming info as opposed to other template overrides available because that is the one that has a `foreach` for rows. In your override you can add a counter to the `foreach()` along with an `if($counter%10 == 0) { ... }` with some markup or call to a block or something like that.

Comment: It's best to add the extra stuff with a variable via a preprocessing, but I've found this more flexible than messing with the $view directly.

Comment: Agreed. If the user can get away with hook_views_pre_render() for hir use case, that's preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement [hook_views_pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7). Loop through and append, edit,  or create new entries into `$view->result` as needed.

Using this approach you'd be injecting hand-picked stuff into your Views raw resultset and might be limited in your row style output unless you digged into Views quite a bit to override the row display handler (which I think is doable).

Answer (score 0):

I think doing it in hook_views_post_execute works best.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
 */
function my_module_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  $entity_id = my_module_fetch_entity_id(); //Random function
  $view->result[] = (object) [
    'entity' => $entity_id,
  ];
}
```

Source: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/intracto/eax4/drupal-insert-an-entity-in-a-views-result

Comment: That is restricted to an entity though. What if it was arbitrary code or a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print custom code after every nth (for example 4th) row **and keep the odd/even sequence** you can simply edit default views template.

Place right into your theme's folder this file `views-view-unformatted--taxonomy-term--page.tpl.php` with this code and you will see "*Your custom code goes here*" text after 4th row in default *Taxonomy term views*:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div class="<?php
  switch ($id) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 8:
    //add more IDs if you have more rows than 10 in your views
      $myclasses = 'views-row-even row';
    break;

    default:
      $myclasses = 'views-row-odd row';
  }  
  print $myclasses; ?>"><?php print $row; ?></div>
  <?php if ($id == 3): ?>
    <div class="views-row-odd row">Your custom code goes here</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Based on this solution: http://www.jasom.net/how-to-add-custom-code-adsense-after-first-row-in-drupal-7-and-drupal-8-views-one-line-solution