# Output a field on every second/third row in views

Tags: 7, views, theming

Is it possible to output a certain views field on every nth row (loop) instead of every row?  Thank you

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52924/insert-whatever-every-nth-row-in-views