# Insert html in views every nth element

Tags: 8

I want to insert `<div class="clearfix"></div>` every nth element. How can I insert this into the twig template of a view?

Same Question for D7: [Insert *whatever* every nth row in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52924/insert-whatever-every-nth-row-in-views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In twig you can use `|batch()`.

For example to group the view in groups of 5 and add a div container around each group:

**views-view-unformatted.html.twig**

```
{% for group in rows|batch(5) %}
  <div class="group">
  {% for row in group %}
    <div{{ row.attributes }}>
      {{ row.content }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried:

<div class="row"> 
                        {% for group in rows|batch(2) %}
         {% for row in group %}
        {{ row }}
         {% endfor %}
         <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>

Comment: Did not work.. Not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: The clearfix gets added after the last element not the second.

Comment: Probably there is only one row

Comment: You are correct. I need to add the clearfix after each item. Not sure how I would do that though. {{ row.content  }} does not give me any output. I'm using global custom text with twig markup.

Comment: If you are in a different template you have other variables.